# populate cells defined by dates period

Tags: date, google-sheets, populate

Sorry if the post is in fact a duplicate. Just could not google anything similar and I am bit stuck on approach. 
I am trying to populate cells in one sheet depending on date in rows of a different sheet, like these:

Sheet1 - entry sheet

```
ID | Name | Start date | End date
10 | Mike | 1.06.2016  | 2.06.2016
13 | Dido | 1.06.2016  | 5.06.2016
8  | Rene | 2.06.2016  | 20.06.2016
```

Sheet2 - report sheet

```
 ids/dates  | 1.06.2016 | 2.06.2016 | 3.06.2016 | date+1
  8         |           | Rene      | Rene      | Rene 
 10         | Mike      | Mike      |           |
 13         | Dido      | Dido      | Dido      | Dido
```

Column **Name** cell's are to be populated in sheet2 depending on Sheet1 Column ID, Start date, end date. The position of the populated cell is defined in sheet2 by column ID and row Dates that should equal the same values in sheet1.

Comment: Mark flag was any value or conditional formating. I removed it and put one more column - name. Cell name should be populated depending on ID and date range.

Answer (score 0):

This report could be done with help of one formula. Please, [check this Example File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G5LGly1sJpCYwUw6IlljKD7uwyp_4gZpbXAl-Nfm0hI/edit#gid=1977867181).

---

**Assumptions**

Suppose, you have Sheet1 with data:

- Col A: ID
- Col B: Name
- Col C: Start date
- Col D: End Date

---

**Case 1. ID's are unique.**

Go to Sheet2 and paste this formula in it:

```
={{"ids/dates";filter(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A<>"")},{ArrayFormula(add(MIN(Sheet1!C:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))-1));ArrayFormula(if(--(add(MIN(Sheet1!C:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))-1)>=filter(Sheet1!C2:C,Sheet1!C2:C<>0))*--(add(MIN(Sheet1!C:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))-1)<=filter(Sheet1!D2:D,Sheet1!C2:C<>0))=1,VLOOKUP(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A<>""),Sheet1!A:B,2,0),""))}}
```

That's all. Report will expand automatically when new data arrives on Sheet1. The report will return error if Data is not complete (misssing Names or dates) on Sheet1.

---

**Case 2. ID's are NOT unique.**

This solution works when ID's are not unique, ID's will be grouped together. One ID belongs to one person in this case.

The formula will be a bit longer:

```
={{"ids/dates";sort(UNIQUE(filter(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A<>"")))},{ArrayFormula(add(MIN(Sheet1!C:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))-1));ArrayFormula(if(QUERY(QUERY({filter(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A<>""),ArrayFormula((--(add(MIN(Sheet1!C:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))-1)>=filter(Sheet1!C2:C,Sheet1!C2:C<>0))*--(add(MIN(Sheet1!C:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))-1)<=filter(Sheet1!D2:D,Sheet1!C2:C<>0))))},"select Col1, sum(Col"&JOIN("), sum(Col",ArrayFormula(COLUMN(OFFSET(B2,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))))&") group by Col1"),"Select Col"&JOIN(", Col",ArrayFormula(COLUMN(OFFSET(B2,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))))&" where Col1>0",0)=1,VLOOKUP(sort(UNIQUE(filter(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A<>""))),Sheet1!A:B,2,0),""))}}
```

See [example here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GihQOwCsNTvge7hXZhXigcJRYRwcBFkN9qjb8_0mtGU/edit#gid=1977867181)

---

**Case 3. IDs are NOT unique. One ID <> one name**

Here's [working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WjCmMR_NLiCnhrej16KSZa-IvDnI6-4YbbnrF66tZyU/edit?usp=sharing), please check it. This case is the hardest one. We can have multiple IDs referring to multiple names. The final formula:

```
={{"ids/dates",ArrayFormula(add(MIN(Sheet1!C:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))-1))};{sort(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A<>""))),ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(QUERY(QUERY({FILTER(Sheet1!A2:B,Sheet1!A2:A<>""),ArrayFormula(--(add(MIN(Sheet1!C:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))-1)>=filter(Sheet1!C2:C,Sheet1!C2:C<>0))*--(add(MIN(Sheet1!C:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))-1)<=filter(Sheet1!D2:D,Sheet1!C2:C<>0))*row(OFFSET(A1,,,rows(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:B,Sheet1!A2:A<>"")))))},"select Col1, sum(Col"&JOIN("), sum(Col",ArrayFormula(COLUMN(OFFSET(C1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))))&") group by Col1"),"Select Col"&JOIN(", Col",ArrayFormula(COLUMN(OFFSET(B2,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))))&" where Col1>0",0),{ArrayFormula(row(OFFSET(A1,,,rows(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:B,Sheet1!A2:A<>""))))),FILTER(Sheet1!A2:B,Sheet1!A2:A<>"")},3,0)))}}
```

The formula will work incorrectly if two Date ranges intersect:

```
102   Mike   6/21/2016  6/27/2016
102   Mike   6/11/2016  6/22/2016
```

Comment: Great. I will have a week of grasping how it works. One problem though, IDs are not unique, they are reacquiring for different dates and names. Its not row unique IDs.

Comment: Does one ID belong to one person only?

Comment: No, sometimes name change.

Comment: You may not find the solution without clear explanation on what target you wish to get. Simple way to get around is to split your task: 1. get all dates from first date in list to the last. 2. Get all IDs, if they repeat, then you need to reproduce all list of unique pairs (name / ID). 3. Get names in intersection of dates and IDs / names in certain condition. Try to start with dates list. You can get it using the formula: `=ArrayFormula(add(MIN(Sheet1!C:D),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,MAX(Sheet1!C:D)-MIN(Sheet1!C:D)))-1))`. This formula will reproduse pairs (ID + name): `=sort(UNIQUE((Sheet1!A2:B)))`

Comment: Max, thank you. Based on your input, I will play and find the solution. My fault is that I oversimplified the case. And I am surprised  that a formula in one cell populates a whole sheet. I am, rather, trying to manually put all IDs in the report-sheet, because they are finite and unique and only on their row depending on date column populate name, color, etc. I also know the dates range - min, max, so I would fix them too on top. Hence I am willing to put formulas in all cells below dates and on the right of IDs that will lookup up in entry-sheet if they should be populated.

Comment: I am trying to reverse construct your formula, but with no success. Here is my perfect example of what I try to achieve [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hAaX5P7uX-4FYvarPKUpolUVYWYmKaYd-RwxQjZP4P0/edit?usp=sharing) . Can you help one last time.